# Object Hash Mapping for a primitive Java Map (Mapping POJO's into Map)

Tags: java, orm

Are there any "Object Hash Mapping" like [this](https://github.com/xetorthio/johm) for the primitive java.util.Map?

The basic idea to be able to "map" custom made classes (usually by annotation) to be stored in a primitive map:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
Class car = new Car(1, "Red"); 

Ohm ohm = new Ohm(map); // set the back-end map to use. 
Car result = ohm.put(car); // persist annotated class
result = ohm.get(1); // get by id
result = ohm.get("color", "Red"); // get by property query
```

One reason I ask this is because I have developed a library that effectively maps the `GAE Datastore` to primitive `Map` interface:

```
Map<String, String> map = Datastorecast.getMap("somemap");
```

Anyway I've been thinking on how to implement it without re-inventing the wheel:

- Using Google Gson or JSON.Simple to serialize an Object into java.util.Map
- One other option for serialization is XStream
- The from there copy the resulting map to the Datastore-backed map container

**Update:**

I realized a technique to achieve this (Redis-style):

```
Class car = new Car(1, "Red"); 

map.put("classname:com.mycompany.Car:uid:", car.getId());
map.put("classname:com.mycompany.Car:color:", car.getColor());
```

- So its just a matter of annotating the class so that the OHM class can reflect the values to put into the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about trove4j [TCustomHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TCustomHashMap.html)? It seems, it could be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but looking at it, looks like it still a Map interface. I actually have a persistent map already (with an interface java.util.Map) what I am actually looking for is something that "maps" a POJO into a set of Map puts or something like that implementation.